# Checking one-one and onto

Tags: functions

Please help me in the following question.

> Let $A=\{x^2\mid0<x<1\}$ and $B=\{x^3\mid1<x<2\}$. Which of the following statements is true?
>
> $1.$ There is a one to one, onto function from A to B.
>
> $2.$ There is no one to one, onto function from A to B taking rationals to rationals.
>
> $3.$ There is no one to one function from A to B which is onto.
>
> $4.$ There is no onto function from A to B which is one to one.

I think the function $(\sqrt(x^2)+1)^3$ is one-one and onto. So answer should be $1$st option.

Is my answer correct? And is there any other function from $A$ to $B$ which is both one-one and onto?

Comment: $A = (0,1)$ and $B=(1,8)$, so $x \mapsto 7x+1$ works, right?

Comment: Statement one is certainly true since both sets have the same cardinality, 2., 3. and 4. are false. And there are lots of these functions which are one-to-one and onto since they not neccessarily must be continuous and given by some formula like yours... There are infinitely many of those functions!

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan- I wish you post it as answer.

Comment: @Alex I saw your comment to late... I made the same argument...

Answer (score 2):

Both $A$ and $B$ are uncountable sets. So there exists a bijection $\phi_1$ from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and a bijection $\phi_2$ from $ B$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The inverse function of a bijection is also a bijection. Note that the composition of two bijections is also a bijection. Now look at $\phi_1 \circ \phi_2^{-1}$. It is a bijection from $A$ to $B$. So normally there should be infintely many bijections.

Notation: A bijection is an onto and one-to-one function. This terminology is not so common in anglo-saxon undergrad textbooks to my experience.

Comment: @Ramit If you really want to be rigorous you should make some kind of argument for the (admittedly trivial) statement that A and B have the same cardinality. Alex White was right to use this terminology. Remember that sets can be uncountable but have different cardinalities $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_2$ for instance.

Comment: @Leo- Can u pls give me an example of uncountable sets having different cardinalities?

Comment: @Ramit- Yes of course! Look at $\mathbb{R}$ and its powerset.